# Dictionary of classes that implement a generic interface

Tags: c#, generics, factory

I have a generic interface with two type parameters with severe generic constraints, and several implementations for different combinations.

```
public interface IResolver<TIn, TOut> where ... {...}
```

I want to create a (static) resolver factory that will store instances of the known implementations, and just serve them, along the lines:

```
public static ResolverFactory{

   public static IResover<TIn, TOut>  GetResolver<TIn, TOut> where ... ()
   {
       //access some storage dictionary to return the correctly typed instance
   }
}
```

How can I create such a containter, that will store both `IResover<Entity1, Entity2>` and `IResolver<Entity3, Entity4>`?

One option I can think of is to use a separate non-generic "marker" interface like:

```
public interface IResolver {} 
public interface IResolver<TIn, TOut> : IResolver where .... 
{...}
```

and use

```
Dictionary<Type, Dictionary <Type, IResolver>> storage;

public RegisterResolver(IResolver resolver)
{
   //add to storage - how?
}
```

but this scenario basically invalidates the constraints put on the generic parameters.
Also when adding the `IResolver`, getting the generic types of the `IResolver<TIn, TOut>` is more or less impossible.

Is there a better solution to this?

Comment: I wouldn't say it invalidates the constraints. It's still an *instance of* `IResolver<TIn, TOut>`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your issue with invalid constraints. Those constraints only matter outside of your ResolverFactory, and are enforced by the signature of your `GetResolve<TIn, TOut>` method. Inside of the ResolverFactory, the way you store the objects doesn't matter.

Comment: @KooKiz: Yes, the same constraints are on the `GetResolver` method, so it will be impossible to get an invalid result, but it will still be possible to register an `IResolver` implementation that is not an `IResolver<TIn, TOut>`

Comment: Maybe I missed something, the common IResolver interface seems nice, but why don't you just make RegisterResolver generic ? public RegisterResolver<TIn, TOut>(IResolver<TIn, TOut> resolver)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be something obvious I'm missing in your question, because I don't understand where the issue is.

First, I declare a `IResolver<TIn, TOut>` interface with a constraint:

```
public interface IResolver<TIn, TOut>
    where TIn : Stream 
{

}
```

Then, I create a `ResolverFactory`, where the constraints are enforced by both the `RegisterResolver` and `GetResolver` method. The way the objects are actually stored doesn't matter, because the storage isn't exposed outside of the class. The encapsulation maintains the consistency:

```
public static class ResolverFactory
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, object> storage = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    public static void RegisterResolver<TIn, TOut>(IResolver<TIn, TOut> resolver) where TIn : Stream 
    {
        storage[typeof(IResolver<TIn, TOut>)] = resolver;
    }

    public static IResolver<TIn, TOut> GetResolver<TIn, TOut>() where TIn : Stream
    {
        return storage[typeof(IResolver<TIn, TOut>)] as IResolver<TIn, TOut>;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Yes, making the `Register` generic will do the trick, I guess. In that case I can make the non-generic interface internal, and limit it's usage within my assembly.

Answer (score 2):

Like KooKiz's answer, but no casting, and no dictionary. Usage is similar.

```
//Rather than:
var res = ResolverFactory.GetResolver<Stream, Hat>();
//You Do:
var res = ResolverFactory<Stream, Hat>.GetResolver();
```

Just moved the generic parameters, with added advantage of defining generic constraints in fewer places.

```
public interface IResolver<TIn, TOut>
    where TIn : Stream
{
}

//Still static, but now there is one per TIn,TOut pair
//so no need for dictionary, so also no need for casting.
public static class ResolverFactory<TIn, TOut> where TIn : Stream
{
    private static IResolver<TIn, TOut> _resolver;

    public static void RegisterResolver(IResolver<TIn, TOut> resolver)
    {
        _resolver = resolver;
    }

    public static IResolver<TIn, TOut> GetResolver()
    {
        return _resolver;
    }
}


internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ResolverFactory<Stream, Hat>.RegisterResolver(new MyStreamToHatResolver());

        var res = ResolverFactory<Stream, Hat>.GetResolver();
    }
}
```

Comment: This will create a separate static class for each pair of parameters, and since I will need to extend it with some "default" functionalities, it will not work. +1, it's a nice idea.

Comment: Oh indeed. And handling multi-threaded scenarios is easier this way. On the other hand, you lose the ability to list/remove all resolvers, so the right solution depends on the requirements (as usual).

Comment: Sounds like you have big plans for this singleton! I'd be a bit worried about that. Leave it as a resolver. 1 job per class. But if you do add more functionality, it'll still work unless they are also sharing static state? In which case I'd be even more worried.

Comment: @weston: Nah, it's just some fallback logic, that is best done there. And static state won't be an issue, since the resolvers themselves are mainly pure functions.

Comment: @KooKiz good point. Could combine the solutions by moving the dictionary to a separate static class.

Comment: You can add pure functions to my solution. Except you need to provide the generic parameters to invoke them. Or like I say, combine the two solutions.